# Setting playback start/end points in NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, audio, timer, naudio

Is there a way to set the start and end points of the playback in NAudio? Currently I'm using a `Timer` to check `ChannelPosition` periodically and reset it to start position when it reaches the end. Is there a better way available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement your own `IWaveProvider` that wraps a `WaveStream` you can set the `CurrentTime` on your stream and check in the `Read` implementation if you're passed the end time. By setting the time on the underlying stream back to the start time you can make your soundclip loop between two timestamps.

The implementation of the class would look like this:

```
private class StartEndLoopReader:IWaveProvider
{
    private TimeSpan _start;
    private TimeSpan _end;
    private WaveStream _stream;

    public StartEndLoopReader(WaveStream stream, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _stream.CurrentTime = start;
        _start = start;
        _end = end;
    }

    public int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(_stream.CurrentTime);
        if (_stream.CurrentTime>_end)
        {
            // back to start to loop 
            // if you want to stop here, return 0 instead.
            _stream.CurrentTime = _start;
        }

        return _stream.Read(array, offset, count);    
    }

    #region IWaveProvider Members
    public WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return _stream.WaveFormat; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You can use this class as follows:

```
var wo = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOutEvent();
var reader = new StartEndLoopReader(
        new WaveFileReader( @"v1.wav"),
        new TimeSpan(0,0,2), 
        new TimeSpan(0,0,4));

wo.Init(reader);
wo.Play();
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thank you.